# How to Run a R script from Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I have .m file, using which I want to run a  R script. How can I do this.

Matlab File

```
caller.m

%some matlab code

% need to call a R script

%some matlab code
```

R script

```
script.R 

some R code
```

I have both the files in the same folder.

How to run script.R from caller.m?

---

Answer by Drew Steen is in general true, as I found this on most of the places on web.
But what worked for me, I am describing below:

Steps:

1. Append "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.3\bin\x64" to "path" variable .
   This [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) provides procedure to set path in windows 7 os.
   Note that bin\x64 instead of bin, bin didn't worked for me.
2. Restart Matlab.
3. Use exec=system('Rscript.exe script.R') where the current script.R is in the current directory of matlab.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `system` function in MATLAB to execute shell commands. Since you can run R from batch files,

```
executed = system('R CMD BATCH path/script.R')
```

should work. Note that `path` will need to be the correct relative path to your R script from whatever your active directory in MATLAB is. `executed` will evaluate as 0 if the system command executed successfully (which is not the same as the R script executing successfully).

Comment: it's giving an error "'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. "

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja: R must be in your path too (or add the path explicitly), i.e. you should be able to run R from the command line.

Comment: ...thus, the first step to diagnose problem is to open a terminal window, cd to your MATLAB working directory, try to run `R CMD BATCH path/script.R`. Once that works, the solution above should work for you.

Comment: I added R in path, and now it is showing 'The system cannot find the path specified.'