# how to display r console in matlab

Tags: r, matlab, console, displayobject

i am running a R script in MATLAB environment using the "system" command as described in:
[How to Run a R script from Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982212/how-to-run-a-r-script-from-matlab)

my R script takes too long to proceed. when i use the Rstudio itself, the progress is displayed in the r console. but i am not able to see the progress status in matlab screen when i call the R script from Matlab.

how can i see the progress of running the R script.

is there any command for that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the '-echo' option when using the system command

```
[status,cmdout] = system(command,'-echo')
```

http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html

I've used the system function with the -echo option to run ffmpeg from the matlab command window, and the resulting command window output is the identical to what I see in the cmd.exe console.

If this doesn't resolve the issue, can you post some example code of what your doing?